# Where can I find info on the current Windows Server 2003 market share?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Windows Server 2003 extended support ends next year, but my feeling is that it still is widely used (in enterprise).

I'm creating a desktop application and I wanted to know if I should target this old operating system. **Is there a source with recent data on Windows Server 2003 market share?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about operating system popularity and is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm what language you will be developing using, will you be using Visual c#, if this is the case then during development you can choose your .net framework which is compatible with Server 2003. This from what I am aware is all you need to worry about as the .NET framework will contain all of your references, SQL, DDL's etc you require. If there do not then you can package specific libraries as and when required.

I develop for 2008+ and have never had issues running these on Server 2003 even using Powershell commands from the application and SQL connections.

I hope this helps.